# How to parse a nested JSON in Java?

Tags: java, json

I have the following JSON that needs to be parsed in spring controller to get each list (**type**,**tid**,**row**,**rowId**). I already tried creating a class that has **type** , **tid** , **row** and **rowId**, but it doesn't work. I'm guessing it is because of the extra [] in the beginning. Can anyone help me with this?

edited: I tried to remove the [] and it turned out to be an invalid json. Is there any solution to this problem ? I can't change the structure of this json because it is passed by a grid.

```
      {
         "type":"row",
         "tid":"2ec7",
         "row":{
            "webapplication":"stock2",
            "cluster":3434,
            "department":"adver"
         },
         "rowId":"stock2"
      },
      {
         "type":"row",
         "tid":"446d",
         "row":{
            "webapplication":"stock3",
            "cluster":3434,
            "department":"tech"
         },
         "rowId":"stock3"
      }
```

controller class

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

    /**
     * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/a", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {



        return "home";
    }

    public class details{

        private String webapplication;
        private String cluster;
        private String department;
        public String getWebapplication() {
            return webapplication;
        }
        public void setWebapplication(String webapplication) {
            this.webapplication = webapplication;
        }
        public String getCluster() {
            return cluster;
        }
        public void setCluster(String cluster) {
            this.cluster = cluster;
        }
        public String getDepartment() {
            return department;
        }
        public void setDepartment(String department) {
            this.department = department;
        }

    }

    public class webapps {

        private String type;
        private String tid;
        private String rowId;

        private details row;

        public details getRow() {
            return row;
        }
        public void setRow(details row) {
            this.rows = row;
        }
        public String getType() {
            return type;
        }
        public void setType(String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }
        public String getTid() {
            return tid;
        }
        public void setTid(String tid) {
            this.tid = tid;
        }
        public String getRowId() {
            return rowId;
        }
        public void setRowId(String rowId) {
            this.rowId = rowId;
        }


    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String update(HttpServletRequest a) {

        String changes = a.getParameterValues("ig_transactions")[0];
        Gson obj = new Gson();
        webapps Changes = obj.fromJson(changes,webapps.class);
        return "home";
    }

}
```

the "changes" variable will hold the json that I want to parse.

the above code gives me this error

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/trial] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:388)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:209)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:879)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:844)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:793)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:765)
    at com.uehara.trial.HomeController.update(HomeController.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Please post the code of what you have done so that we can respond with respect to that code.

Comment: I just added my controller class in the question.